# How to rerender radio inputs when a state variable changes? [react.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a div containing 4 radio inputs, and another div containing a onClick event that increments a counter. I want that every time I press the div, my inputs rerender so that there isn't any selected input.
This is my code:

```js
'use client'
import { createExam } from '@/req/CreateExam'
import { finishExam } from '@/req/finishExam'

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function TestExam() {
  let token
  // let examId;

  const { data: session } = useSession()

  const [examId, setExamId] = useState('')
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([{ answers: [{}] }]) // Store the questions coming from the request
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({}) // Store the answers from the user

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  const [isCompleted, setIsCompleted] = useState(false)

  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState({ answer: {} })

  // Hard-code exam
  const exam = {
    language: 'fr',
    studentId: '653705c06161b74cd23c3d53'
  }

  if (session) {
    token = session.accessToken
  }

  // Event handlers

  // Generates the exam and get the response
  const handleClick = async () => {
    let res = await createExam({ exam, token })

    if (res.status == '201') {
      console.log(res)

      setQuestions(res.data.questions)
      setExamId(res.data._id)
    }
  }

  const handlePrev = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCount(count - 1)
  }

  const convertAnswers = () => {
    setAnswer({ answers: { answers } })
  }

  const handleNext = async (e) => {
    setCount(count + 1)
    console.log(answers)

    if (count + 1 >= questions.length) {
      convertAnswers()
      console.log(answer)

      console.log('Questions: ' + answers)
      setIsCompleted(true)
      let res = await finishExam({ answer, token, examId })
      console.log(res)
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAnswers({ ...answers, [count]: e.target.value })
  }

  return (
    <main className="p-3">
      <div>
        <section className="items-center text-center justify-center flex flex-col">
          <div
            className="bg-light_green p-4 rounded-xl w-fit text-white"
            onClick={handleClick}
          >
            Generate Examen
          </div>
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Grammar</h1>
          <p className="text-xl">Section {questions[count].section}</p>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h2>{questions[count].question}</h2>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li className="pb-3">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="answer"
                  value={'a'}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                {' a) '}
                {questions[count].answers[0].a}
              </li>
              <li className="pb-3">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="answer"
                  value={'b'}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                {' b) '}
                {questions[count].answers[0].b}
              </li>
              <li className="pb-3">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="answer"
                  value={'c'}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                {' c) '}
                {questions[count].answers[0].c}
              </li>
              <li className="pb-3">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  name="answer"
                  value={'d'}
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                />
                {' d) '}
                {questions[count].answers[0].d}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
          <div className="bg-light_green text-lg px-5 py-2 rounded-lg">
            {count + 1}/{questions.length}
          </div>
          <div
            className="bg-secondary rounded-md px-10 py-3"
            onClick={handleNext}
          >
            Next
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h2>Answers</h2>
          {JSON.stringify(answer)}
        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I've seen I could use the useEffect hook, but I don't know how could I apply it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to reset the inputs. The trick is to connect them to the correct state and they update/reset automatically.

I'll exemplify with some code.
Say you have some questions objects of this type:

```
type QuestionType {
  question: string
  options: string[]
}
```

.. and you save the user's answers in an object, where the question is the key and the selected answer is the option:

```
const answers = {
  "What is the capital of France?": "Paris",
  "Who wrote the play 'Romeo and Juliet'?": "William Shakespeare",
  ...
}
```

If you use a Question component along these lines:

```
const Question = ({ question, options, answer, setAnswer }) => (
  <div className="question">
    <h4>{question}</h4>
    {options.map((option, key) => (
      <label key={option}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={key}
          checked={answer === option}
          onChange={() => setAnswer({ [question]: option })}
        />
        {option}
      </label>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

...you can then render the "current" question using:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({})
  const setAnswer = useCallback((answer) => {
    setAnswers((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...answer }));
  }, [])
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
  const { question, options } = questions[currentIndex];
  return (
    <Question
      {...{
        question,
        options,
        answer: answers[question],
        setAnswer,
        key: question,
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Bare bones implementation:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, Fragment } = React
const questions = [
  {
    question: 'What is the capital of France?',
    options: ['Madrid', 'Berlin', 'Paris', 'Rome']
  },
  {
    question: "Who wrote the play 'Romeo and Juliet'?",
    options: [
      'Charles Dickens',
      'William Shakespeare',
      'George Orwell',
      'Jane Austen'
    ]
  },
  {
    question: 'What is the chemical symbol for gold?',
    options: ['Fe', 'Ag', 'Au', 'Cu']
  },
  {
    question: "What is the largest planet in our solar system?",
    options: ["Saturn", "Jupiter", "Venus", "Mars"]
  }
]
const Question = ({ question, options, answer, setAnswer }) => (
  <div className="question">
    <h4>{question}</h4>
    {options.map((option, key) => (
      <label key={option}>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value={key}
          checked={answer === option}
          onChange={() => setAnswer({ [question]: option })}
        />
        {option}
      </label>
    ))}
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({})
  const setAnswer = useCallback((answer) => {
    setAnswers((prev) => ({ ...prev, ...answer }))
  }, [])
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)
  const { question, options } = questions[currentIndex]
  const move = useCallback(
    (step) =>
      setCurrentIndex(
        (prev) => (questions.length + prev + step) % questions.length
      ),
    []
  )
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Question
        {...{
          question,
          options,
          answer: answers[question],
          setAnswer,
          key: question
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={() => move(-1)}>Prev</button>
      <button onClick={() => move(1)}>Next</button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ currentIndex, answers }, null, 2)}</pre>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```css
.question {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As you can see, there's no need to reset the selected option because we link it to the `answers` object.

In more detail, the `checked` prop's value of every radio button is driven by `answer === option`, which translates to `answers[question] === option`. And that's all you need.

Any unanswered question will have no radio checked, because `answers[question]` returns `undefined` until it's answered, and any answered question will have whatever the user last cliked on, for that question.

Here's a [more polished implementation](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quirky-goldwasser-xfnm32?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A40%2C35), on Vite, with TypeScript). The questions are random and dynamic, courtesy of [Open trivia database](https://opentdb.com/).